# Configuring IBM DB2 ODBC - Changing the Host IP / Alias already exists

Tags: windows, db2, odbc

I've created an IBM ODBC connection to my server via Microsoft's own ODBC Administrator. After initially finding difficulties on where to put in the IP Address (otherwise, the ODBC uses my local database server), it finally managed to connect to my server PC successfully.

During this process, however, I did not put in a Database Alias, as I did not know what it means, nor what it is for. The ODBC still works fine.

The server, however, changed its IP Address. I don't know how or why it does that, and how to stop it, but now my previously working ODBC is now unable to connect, saying it gave an error message at 192.168.1.127, the server's previous IP Address.

I tried, and failed, to find out how to change the Host IP via the ODBC configuration.

In frustration, I deleted the ODBC connection, created a new one under System DSN, etc., etc., but upon clicking finish, it says the alias URCDB already exists.

How can I solve these problems?

Note:

- URCDB is the name of my database. In both occasions, I did not put
  anything in the alias field.
- There are two URCDBs during the ODBC creation process. One was for
  the local test database I used to have on my PC (deleted), the other,
  I guess, was the left over from the recently deleted ODBC to my
  Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:
1. Create a DSN with different alias.
When creating DSN give the original database name in database name filed and in alias field provide different name other than origina database name.

1. uncatalog the database name using the below command

   go to run --> type db2cmd
   db2 uncatalog database **database name**

now open ODBC create the DSN with giving DSN name and alias name as original **database name**

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your server has DHCP enabled whereas servers shoud have a static IP address.  Hope this helps. DHCP addresses are usually consistent but depending on what level network protocols are in place, the can and will likely change at some point.